# Sql server has detected a non canonical discretionary access control list

Tags: sql-server-2008

After installing SQL Server 2008 Enterprise I received three error messages like this: Setup has detected a non canonical discretionary access control list (DACL) on directory 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM'. Please verify your security settings and make corrections if needed.

What's going on or what I should do?

Answer (score 3):

An access control list is a list of access control entries (ACEs), and there is a specific order for the ACEs. The order matters because when checking an ACL Windows will stop as soon as it finds a matching ACE, whether it's a deny or permit. So deny ACEs should be first, then allow ACEs and finally inherited ACEs.

Anyhow, the point is that the error means the ACEs are out of order. The easiest solution is to add some random user to the ACL then take them out again. Explorer should put the ACEs into the correct order when it makes any change, so adding and removing an entry should fix the ACL.

JR